# Find the product of two sums via SMPC

Tags: secret-sharing, dsa, multiparty-computation

I'm currently working on a distributed threshold DSA scheme that requires to find the product of two sums via secure multi-party computation.
Specifically speaking, every one of $n$ parties $P_i$ possesses a DSA key pair $(sk_i, pk_i)$, where $sk_i=d_i \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and $pk_i = g^{d_i}$. I want to collectively generate a signature $S_{\Sigma} = k_{\Sigma}^{-1}(m+r_{\Sigma}d_{\Sigma})$, where$k_{\Sigma}=k_1+\dots k_n$, $r_{\Sigma}d_{\Sigma}=(r_1+\dots+r_n)\cdot(d_1+\dots+d_n)$. My prior question is that is there a proper paradigm to compute $r_{\Sigma}d_{\Sigma}$ without leaking information about secret keys $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$? For computing $k_{\Sigma}$, I'm using the [BGW Protocol](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221590203_Completeness_Theorems_for_Non-Cryptographic_Fault-Tolerant_Distributed_Computation_Extended_Abstract?enrichId=rgreq-b4e579f273d5ba523aa345642bb384b3-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyMTU5MDIwMztBUzoxMDE5NjA0ODkzNzM3MTBAMTQwMTMyMDY4NDc2OA%3D%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf) and Shamir threshold secret sharing scheme. Is it possible to compute $r_{\Sigma}d_{\Sigma}$ using BGW protocol as well?

PS: I'm new to SMPC, and English is not my first language. Sorry for the troubles. Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to compute the product of two secret numbers (in your case r*d), then, you can use Beaver's multiplication triple to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, see for example [this page](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/bgw.html). Note that multiplication requires $O(n^2)$ additional communication, in contrast to addition (which is free).